# Валидация json-файла

Tags: php, json

Есть файл json, в котором лежат параметры. Вопрос, как в PHP проверить валидность файла? Ниже дана json схема.

```
    {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name"   
  ]
}
```

Comment: `json_decode()`, а потом `json_last_error()`

Comment: @ArchDemon и вы тоже ничего не поняли, как и автор удалённого ответа. Нужно не эту json-схему проверить, а наоборот проверить json-файл этой схемой (см. текущий ответ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "justinrainbow/json-schema": "^5.2"
}
}
```

data_invalid.json:

```
{"testtwo" : "test"}
```

data.json:

```
{"name" : "test"}
```

schema.json

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "name": {
    "type": "string"
  }
},
"required": [
  "name"
]
```

}

index.php

```
<?php
 // Не забываем про composer install перед запуском
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'));

// Validate
$validator = new JsonSchema\Validator;
$validator->validate($data, (object)['$ref' => 'file://' . realpath('schema.json')]);

if ($validator->isValid()) {
    echo "The supplied JSON validates against the schema.\n";
} else {
    echo "JSON does not validate. Violations:\n";
    foreach ($validator->getErrors() as $error) {
        echo sprintf("[%s] %s\n", $error['property'], $error['message']);
    }
}
```